# Update days based on selected month

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple Javascript function to update the days in a select box whenever the month is changed:

```
/* automatically update days based on month */
function updateMonth(iMonth, iDay) {
    var el = document.getElementById(iDay);
    el.options.length = 0;
    var d = new Date();
    for(i = 0; i < (32 - new Date(d.getFullYear(), iMonth, 32).getDate()); i++) {
        option = new Option(i, i);
        el.options[i] = option;
    }
}

<select name="start_month" id="start_month" onchange="updateMonth(this.value, 'start_day');">
<option>...</option>
</select>
<select name="start_day" id="start_day">
<option>...</option>
</select>
<select name="start_year" id="start_year">
<option>...</option>
</select>
```

First of all it appears to be updating but I'm getting crazy results. February gives me 30 days, January 27, and they all start with 0? Secondly I'm not sure if I need to consider the year in addition to the month?

Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/NK7yd/

Comment: Complete your code or provide a jsFiddle

Comment: Subtract 1 from the month number as the Date() month number is base 0.

Comment: @PiLHA I added jsFiddle.

Comment: I managed to do this using jQuery. See it solves your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/NK7yd/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should be

```
window.updateMonth= function(iMonth, iDay) {
    var el = document.getElementById(iDay);
    el.options.length = 0;

    for(var d = new Date(2013,iMonth-1,1); d.getMonth()==iMonth-1; d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)) {
        option = new Option(d.getDate(), d.getDate());
        el.options[d.getDate()-1] = option;
    }; 
}
```

I is necessary to read value from select with years (instead of hard coded 2013).
http://jsfiddle.net/b5XMM/3/

Comment: This seems to work except when the month is changed, the default day is set to blank rather than the first day, and the day numbers aren't padded... Can you help me with those issues?

Comment: Corrected. The first element was omitted and so was empty.